# field value equals to max value from another table

Tags: ms-access

i want to create a database that contains a table for all of my Archives(which contains persons name and personal) and i want to have a table for each different person and i want one of Archives fields to be last record (which is the id of last record in each of those other tables)
first i need to define the the name for each row as a variable and then use it to access last record like
name = tim and select max(name.lastrecord)[image]
can it be done in access or should i use something?

Comment: _I want to have a table for each different person_ ... no you don't. What you need is to find a primer on _Database normalisation_ and one for _Beginning with Microsoft Access_ or similar.

Comment: Most anything can be done with enough code. However, what you describe makes no sense for a relational database structure.